# How to Add Dynamic Image to Docusign Document via Docusign API

Tags: c#, sdk, docusignapi

I don't know if this is possible with the Docusign API, but I was curious if you can add dynamic images to a template document. The purpose of this dynamic image would be to set a logo for the document depending on who's sending it. I know Docusign has branding, but we would like this image to be in a particular location on the template document. If anyone knows if this is possible, I would be extremely happy if you can point me in the right direction.

I've done plenty of research and checked a little into the c# SDK and I'm not seeing too much on how to implement something like this.

Any information on this would help or even some kind of workaround.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please upvote all useful answers including those to others' questions. And please check/accept the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use image `A` in a specific location within the document (or image `B`, etc).

This is an aspect of the document itself. So you'll need to send DocuSign a new document (that contains the different image) each time.

To put it another way, you want custom document generation. There are several ways to accomplish custom document generation with DocuSign:

- Use the [DocuSign document generation](https://www.docusign.com/products/gen) system.
- Create the document on the fly. Depending on your needs, one easy format is to send DocuSign an HTML document. Note that you'll need to BASE64 encode the image(s) and use inline CSS.
- Create/update the document on the fly by creating a custom PDF. There are many PDF libraries to choose from.
- Create/update another format such as Word. You can programmatically change Word documents.

**Added**

Another option for creating a document is to supply HTML as part of the Responsive Signing / Smart Sections feature. This enables you to create an HTML document that includes the field (tab) definitions within the HTML itself. [Documentation part 1](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/api-overview). (See the navigation pane for the additional docs.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've thought of the two middle bullet points. I feel like those are viable options in most instances, but I have a lot of tab fields on this document (over 200) and I'm not sure if the field names and locations would have to be reset in code, which would be a pain. I'm definitely looking for an easier solution, but from what I've researched, this seems like the best option.

Comment: @user3002092 -- see my updated answer for another option.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer Larry. That seems a little more like the direction I'd want to take. I'm going to look into it, but from the sound of it, it looks like it can do what I want it to do. I'll accept this as the correct answer. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: some css properties like width and position are ignored