# Best way to send docusign replaceable contracts

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

What is the best way to send docusign contracts in a way that allows them to be editable during the envelope creation process?

See in [DocuSign Documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing), we can see how to create documents and then attach them to the envelope:

```
docPdfBytes = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('demoDocsPath', 'pdf1File.pdf'));
// add the documents
let doc1 = new docusign.Document()
  , doc1b64 = Buffer.from(docPdfBytes).toString('base64')
  ;

doc1.documentBase64 = doc1b64;
doc1.name = 'Lorem Ipsum'; // can be different from actual file name
doc1.fileExtension = 'pdf';
doc1.documentId = '3';
```

An alternative that I found and that allows you to send a document where it is possible to make 'replaces' to fill in things like "name, address" is to save HTML in a string, instead of a pure PDF.

Docusign requires you to convert my file to base64, which will be transformed at the end of the request into a final PDF with the docusign configuration. The problem is when there are images in the HTML file, during HTML conversion -> 64 -> PDF, the images are not treated in a faithful way, for example, when there is a watermark, the PDF returns a page with the watermark and the misaligned body, see the example: [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubkOk.png) and [what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blqjj.png).

Is there a better way to send replaceable documents? If not, how can you force the final PDF to respect CSS properties?

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques for creating custom documents. See my [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250316/64904)

With regards to your question:

Base64 is an encoding technique. It has zero impact on the document.

The real issue you're facing is that the DocuSign conversion from HTML to PDF is not as sophisticated as your use case needs. For these types of use cases, I recommend that you create the PDF yourself.

There are many PDF creation libraries that enable your software to create exactly the PDF that you want.

If you only need to customize a form, you can use DocuSign tags (fields) to hold the dynamic data. Your application can set tags to have values from your data and either allow or not allow the document recipients to change the data as part of the signing process.

You can use an HTML original to specify the tags (see my other answer), or you can add the tags to your PDF document. Best is to use anchor text for that.