# Docusign - Upload a HTML Template

Tags: html, css, docusignapi

When i upload on the screen ["prepare template"](https://app.docusign.com/prepare-template/), some css properties, like `position: absolute` and `width` are neglected. How to upload HTML with a faithful css?

I did as said in [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250316/13842275), but not solve.

HTML example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%;background-color: blueviolet; position: absolute;">TEXTE
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%;background-color: yellow;">
           
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Results in Docusign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeIeQ.png)  and  [Results in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMbCM.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using production and not using an API as a developer.

You would need to contact sales/support to enable responsive signing feature for your account.
If you [create a developer account](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/) - you can do this for free.
The [following article](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/api-overview) explains how.

Comment: it's in the post, the back-end code I consider irrelevant, because in the example I uploaded it manually through the platform and the problem is the same